Can I use this response to this question?

A: What’s there behind the door?
B: They are two dogs.

Does B’s response sound acceptable?

details please what is your doubt about this conversation?

I am wondering whether both “there are two dogs”  and “they are two dogs” are both acceptable.

There are. not they are. They are boys, not girls. There are boys in the classroom. Surely, those are different in your language?

I agree with others saying this doesn't work. However, similar cases do arise: "Who wrote this book?" "She's a Finnish botanist who's done a lot of work with etc etc…" I can't really put my finger on why this is any different from the example, but maybe someone else can.

It might be marginally acceptable if the door was made of glass, possibly translucent glass of the sort used in toilet doors, and A could see there was some kind of animal but didn't know exactly what. I'm guessing that is not the precise scenario intended here.

@StuartF Although the normal question in that context would probably be "What are those behind the door?" "those" in the question becomes "they" in the answer.

@the-baby-is-you That still sounds unnatural to me. A more idiomatic answer would just be "A Finnish botanist..." (no subject or verb needed) or "The author was a Finnish botanist...". The pronoun seems weird unless the question is something like "Tell me about the author of this book."

@Barmar It occurs to me that part of what it achieves is putting the personal pronoun front and center, which not only shows how to refer to them but individualizes them to some extent, even suggesting the speaker has some depth of knowledge on them (and might keep talking for a while). This feels logical to me but I'm way too tired to analyze why, and no idea how to apply this to the dog question.

you could say it is a pair of dogs

No. It is not acceptable.  The pronoun "They" is missing a reference.
The answer tells us that "They" are "two dogs".  For that to make sense then the person must not know this information.  So the reference of "They" isn't "two dogs". There is nothing else that "they" could refer to.  This means that "They" has no reference, and that is a mistake.
They are two dogs" would be an answer to "What are those animals over there?"   In which case, "they" is a reference to "those animals".
The simple way to answer this question is with a noun phrase  "Two dogs".  You don't need a subject and a sentence. If required then use the dummy subject, "There are two dogs."

I would say "There are two dogs".  If the "there" was missing in the question then "they" might work.
